# Is it always true that $\bigcap_{n\in \mathbb{N}} U_n \not = \emptyset$?

Tags: general-topology

Let be $\{U_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ dense and open subsets of a second countable space $X$.

Is it always true that  $\bigcap_{n\in \mathbb{N}} U_n \not = \emptyset$?

Answer (score 3):

No, take $X=\Bbb Q$ in the usual topology (certainly second countable) and let $n \to q_n$ be an enumeration of $\Bbb Q$, and $U_n = \Bbb Q \setminus \{q_n\}$, which is dense and open and $\bigcap_n U_n = \emptyset$.